# Polynomial Problem $P(x)=x^{100}-100x+99$

Tags: analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)=x^{100}-100x+99$. Prove:

i) $x=1$ is a double root

ii)The polynomial has no other real roots

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i): root is (at least) double iff it's a root of the derivative. ii) 1 is the only real root of $P'(x)$, and it's a single root, so 1 is the only extremum of $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{100}-100x+99$. It is obvious that $1$ is a root of $f(x)$. But $f'(x)=100x^{99}-100$, so $1$ is also a root of $f'(x)$, and therefore $1$ is a root of $f(x)$ of multiplicity at least $2$.
But since $1$ is not a root of $f''(x)$, the root $1$ has multiplicity exactly $2$.

Since $f'(x)=100x^{99}-100$, the function $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[1,\infty]$, so $f(x)$ cannot have a root $\gt 1$.

Since $f(x)$ is decreasing in the interval $(0,1]$ and reaches $0$ at $x=1$, there cannot be a root in the interval $(0,1)$.

Finally, $f(x)$ is positive for $x\le 0$.

Comment: Thanks I just solved it using Horner's method two consecutive times for the first part.

Comment: You are welcome. Since I was going to use calculus to show there are no other roots, I thought that one might as well use it for the rest. Note that to show $1$ is a double root, one must show that it is not, for example, a triple root.

Comment: Yeah i know that thanks for the heads-up. I just figured out another way to solve the second part.  From the first part: $P(x)=(x-1)^2(x^{98}+2x^{97}+3x^{96}...+98x+99)$.

If $x\geq0$ then $P(x)>0 ,\forall x\epsilon R$

That means $P(x)\neq0, \forall x\epsilon \mathbb{R}_{+}-\left \{ -1 \right \}$

If $x<0$ then $x^{100}>0$ and $-100x>0$

We add $x^{100}>0+(-100x>0)= x^{100}-100x>0$

We then add $99$: $x^{100}-100x+99>99$

This means $P(x)\neq0, \forall x<0$

Comment: For $x\lt 0$, there is nothing to do. For $x^{100}\gt 0$, and $-100x\gt 0$, so the function is $\gt 99$.

Comment: I think it should be "*Since $f'(x)$ is negative in the interval $[0,1]$*..."

Comment: Thanks, I meant to say since $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(0,1]$.